# Rebuild HDD: Repair NTFS and MFT

Tags: ntfs, mbr

folks! Newbie here, I hope this is the right area to post a new topic.

So, I got an HDD which got corrupted. 
I will try to be as specific as possible about describing my problem, even if English is not my native language, neither of my computer's interface. Also, I am new to Ubuntu - if you give me any tips, please be accurate. Good, here we go:

Usually I work with a single boot system for Microsoft's Windows 7 on a casual HDD.

The very basic issue is that all files on my main HDD seem to be existent (can be viewed via *Ubuntu live disc* which I am using right now) but the pc's normal booting procedure will not work due to the following reasons: The NTFS signature is missing, error in the attribute bitmap of the MFT *(probably Masterfiletable)* and uncorrectable sectors.

**I am aware that this indicates a physical damage of my HDD but I am confident that there is a way of rebuilding the HDD to a certain degree in order to make it bootable again.**

**Iteration 01: Use the Windows live disc**:
 I tried to run various commands like *chkdsk* and *bootrec* in order to repair the HDD but all attempts failed since no Windows installation can be detected and due to the huge amount of corrupted data. In addition, the hdd has a write protection suddenly.

**Iteration 02: Use Ubuntu live disc**:
 Booting this way, I can mount my hdd and access all my files including even the Windows folder which appears to be alright. 
 Then, I used the terminal to submit ntfsfix. Though, this operation stopped due to the missing NTFS signature. It also said there is a unrecoverable error and that I should run chkdsk. Does this mean I am supposed to run chkdsk via Ubuntu?
 Anyway, I expect the *Master boot record* to be erroneous as well.

So, here is in what way I count on you guys: You might know what commands to run or which applications to use via Ubuntu in order to rebuild everything an HDD needs in order to boot an operating system like Windows 7!
As far as I can tell, we need to repair the HDD's file system (NTFS in my case), its MFT and MBR.

It might be easier to get a new harddrive and clone the current one but I would like to restore as much functionality as possible.

Comment: Not a Linux question. You may get moved. But review this. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

Comment: What do you mean not a Linux question? Is Ubuntu basically not Linux?

Comment: Your problem is with your Windows installation.